# What to do when your questions are closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close

My 2 questions were closed. Just closed. I disagree with simply closing because I'm ready to edit my question until it is accepted. If I would not do this I would agree with closure. Just closing someone's question is the simplest operation in the world, but explaining and helping a person to improve his question is cumbersome. So, some people do the easy stuff.

My recommendation to not allow people to close a question unless they make an effort to help.
When help is given, but a person who asked a question has no response to it, I think then it's quite fair to be closed.

When a question is open and is improved, then many newbies can benefit from the answer posted. When it's simply closed, that is only garbage in the forum.

Let's help each other, my friends!

Comment: Closing is not the end. You can still edit - this will put the question in a reopen queue and if it is good - it will be reopened.

Comment: To edit in correct direction I need arguments. But nothing was asked.

Comment: And what 2 questions are you talking about? I see 36 questions on SO. If you are talking about Unix & Linux, you really should be posting on their Meta.

Comment: As you see now it's downvoted to close this question if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Downvoting is not closing. Two different things. Correlated, but different. As for meta - [downvotes are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Oded: I think in this case the downvote-tooltip hits home.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - Well, it certainly lacks in regards of getting enough context to actually answer the question.

Comment: There's "how to ask", "faq", there's helpful pointers on the page when you're actually asking the question, there are 5.2 million other questions on this site you could review not only to see if your answer already exists, but also to see what questions are good and what questions are not. Frankly, we should not have to explain a single thing to you and when we do, it is a courtesy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reopened one of your questions, [looking for a method that will show tomorrow's date in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17036373/1288), but I feel like I need to justify it because it's really not a great question.  It was closed as "not a real question", which just wasn't accurate.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

It was clear what was being asked. I think people were voting to close it due to a lack of research effort on your part.  They should have just downvoted the question, not closed it.

My advice to you is that you need to stop and think about what you're trying to do and research it a little bit before asking on Stack Overflow. If you know how to get today's date in Ruby, it should not be much of a problem to research how to add one day to that date to get tomorrow's date. Please research your problems more thoroughly in the future.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will!